# How to fetch a list of images based on previously downloaded information?

Tags: dart, flutter, bloc

I have 2 rest API, one is for data and another one is for images. So I do:

1. fetch data.
2. loop over the data.
3. inside each data loop, then fetch the image.

But what happens is that all loaded image always use the last image of the list. This is how I do it:

```
//this is the list fetch
return     
    StreamBuilder(
      stream: myBloc.myList,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Result>> snapshot){
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            //build the list
            return buildList(snapshot);
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
          }
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());        
      },
    );



  Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<List<Result>> snapshot) {
return GridView.builder(
    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
    gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 4),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

      //fetch the image
      myBloc.fetchImageById(snapshot.data[index].Id.toString());

      return
      StreamBuilder(
        stream: myBloc.imageById,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshotImg){
            if (snapshotImg.hasData) {

              return 
              MyPlaceholder(
                imageProvider: snapshotImg.data,
                title: snapshot.data[index].name,
              );

            } else if (snapshotImg.hasError) {

              return 
              MyPlaceholder(
                imageProvider: null,
                title: snapshot.data[index].name,
              );

            }
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());        
        },
      );

    });

  }
```

and this is my BLoC class:

```
class MyBloc {
  final _repository = MyRepository();

  final _fetcher = PublishSubject<List<Result>>();
  final _fetcherImage = PublishSubject<dynamic>();

  Observable<List<Result>> get myList => _fetcher.stream;
  Observable<dynamic> get myImageById => _fetcherImage.stream;

  fetchResultList() async {
    List<Result> result = await _repository.fetchMyList();
    _fetcher.sink.add(result);
  }

  fetchImageById(String _id) async {
    dynamic imgBinary = await _repository.fetchImageById(_id);
    _fetcherImage.sink.add(imgBinary);
  }

  dispose() {
    _fetcher.close();
    _fetcherImage.close();
  }

}

final categoryBloc = CategoryBloc();
```

Did I miss? It's not possible to have bloc Observable inside another bloc?

Comment: What values does the myBloc.imageById stream output?

Comment: @Luksprog wait I'll update my qestion with bloc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But what happens is all loaded image always the last image of the
>   list.

You have a single stream for the images in your BLoC so all corresponding StreamBuilders from your GridView's rows will update only with the last value in the snapshot(and you end up with the last image).

***If you are sure you only have a few images*** that you want to show in your GridView,  you could make the  fetchImageById() method to create a stream for that particular image, keep a reference to it and then return it. The returned stream you could then pass to the row StreamBuilder instead of myBloc.imageById, this way your rows StreamBuilders will have a different data source. When the image is loaded you could add it to that specific stream(based on the id) and your row will be updated only with that specific data. Some code:

```
//fetch the image
Observable<dynamic> imageStream =      myBloc.fetchImageById(snapshot.data[index].Id.toString());
      return StreamBuilder(
        stream: imageStream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshotImg){
// rest of code
```

In your BLoC you'll have:

```
Map<String, PublishSubject<dynamic>> _backingImageStreams = HashMap()

Observable<dynamic> fetchImageById(String _id) {
    PublishSubject<dynamic> backingImgStream = _backingImageStreams[id];
    if (backingImgStream == null) {
        backingImgStream = PublishSubject<dynamic>();
        _backingImageStreams[id] = backingImgStream;
    }
    // i'm assuming that repository.fetchImageById() returns a Future ?!
    _repository.fetchImageById(_id).then((){
        _fetcherImage.sink.add(imgBinary);
    });
    return _fetcherImage.stream;
}
```

**In the more general case**, I think you need to change your code from a StreamBuilder for a FutureBuilder. In your widget you'll have:

```
Widget buildList(AsyncSnapshot<List<Result>> snapshot) {
   // ...
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      //fetch the image
      Future<dynamic> imageFuture = myBloc.fetchImageById(snapshot.data[index].Id.toString());
      return FutureBuilder(
            future: imageFuture,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshotImg){
   // rest of your current code
```

Then you'll need to change your BLoC method fetchImageById(). As you're dealing with images you'll want to implement some sort of cache so you'll be more efficient:

- to not download the same image again if you already have it(and be fast in showing it to the user)
- to not load all the images at once and clutter the memory(or completely fail)

The BLoC code:

```
class MyBloc {
    // remove the imageId observable

    // A primitive and silly cache. This will only make sure we don't make extra 
    // requests for images if we already have the image data, BUT if the user 
    // scrolls the entire GridView we will also have in memory all the image data. 
    // This should be replaced with some sort of disk based cache or something 
    // that limits the amount of memory the cache uses.
    final Map<String, dynamic> cache = HashMap();

    FutureOr<dynamic> fetchImageById(String _id) async {
        // atempt to find the image in the cache, maybe we already downloaded it
        dynamic image = cache[id];
        // if we found an image for this id then we can simply return it
        if (image != null) {
            return image;
        } else {
            // this is the first time we fetch the image, or the image was previously disposed from the cache and we need to get it
           dynamic image = // your code to fetch the image 
           // put the image in the cache so we have it for future requests
           cache[id] = image;
           // return the downloaded image, you could also return the Future of the fetch request but you need to add it to the cache
           return image;
        }
     }
```

If you just want to show the image to the user, just make your fetchImageById() to return a future from the image fetch request(but you'll make a fetch request every time the widget is built).

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog this is excatly I ended up doing and it works. But I still curious about returning image as StreamBuilder. As you said on 2nd paragraph "........ you could make the fetchImageById() method to create a stream for that particular image, keep a reference to it and then return it. The returned stream you could then pass to the row StreamBuilder instead of myBloc.imageById, this way your rows StreamBuilders will have a different data source. When the image is loaded you could add it to that specific stream(based on the id) and your row will be updated only with that specific data."

Comment: Is it possible to have StreamBuilder inside another StreamBuilder? Because I always get the last image.... I ended up using FutureBuilder. And how different it is using StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder for image?

Comment: So how to implement your 2nd paragraph solution above? Not mandatorily because FutureBuilder works just fine. Just for the sake of curiosity.

Comment: @rxlky *So how to implement your 2nd paragraph solution above?* - I've updated my answer with some code. *Is it possible to have StreamBuilder inside another StreamBuilder?* yes, why not, they are both widgets?

Comment: @rxlky *And how different it is using StreamBuilder or FutureBuilder for image?*  - From the perspective of the widget you want to load an image(the future approach), you don't want a stream of images on the same widget(the stream approach).

Comment: @Luksprog...ah I see ok thanks for your elaboration. I'll just do what works. :) But anyway it's still possible to have stream of 1 image right? But what happened was as you said it was stream of images so it was always the last image.

Comment: @rxlky Yes, it's possible  to have a stream of one image. You just need to not share it between widgets.

Comment: @Luksporg one thing if I use dynamic to load image how to add error? (Because there is no fetcher to it) Usually I do List<Category> category = await _repository.fetchCategoryList().catchError((err) => _fetcherTicket.addError(err)); then on Screen I can show it on snapshot.hasError...................---------------------------------------- updated: sorry maybe it can be done just initialize new  _fetcherImg for image

Comment: @rxlky I'm not sure why you can't use catchcError() on the Future from the fetch image request like you did for fetching the category list? It would help to see the code you have.